# scrapy middleware: what the number means (eg. ProxyMiddleware': 410)?

Tags: scrapy, middleware

Sorry for the very basic question but what the `410` means in `myproject.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410` ? (It's so obvious that nobody talk about it!).

```
RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400 
HttpProxyMiddleware': 110
ProxyMiddleware': 100
```

I did not find anything about it in the tuto.

**EDIT** It's not a duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623470/scrapy-middleware-order) : the answers says the number is use to sort the order but doesnt explain why they use a specific number. Why in my example above `RandomUserAgentMiddleware` use 400, why not 399, or 401, is there a reason for that? Or should we roughly take any number that fit in the order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy middleware order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623470/scrapy-middleware-order)

Comment: this values are the middleware orders.

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks but I saw that post. It seems they could chose any number between 1 to 999, but It doesnt explain why they use a specific number. Why  in my exemple above `RandomUserAgentMiddleware` use 400, why not 399, or 401, is there a reason for that? Or should we roughly take `any` number that fit in the order?

Comment: Roughly any number which fits the order and also gives you flexibility to fit some other middleware in between. So you use `100, 200,...` instead of `1,2,3..` which gives you more flexibility when adding middlewares

Comment: Oh I understand, thanks a lot! (If you copy-past it in an answer I will accept it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number could be roughly any number which fits the order and also gives you flexibility to fit some other middleware in between.

So you use `100, 200, 300, ...` instead of `1, 2, 3,...` which gives you more flexibility when adding middlewares in between the existing middlewares. Final the middlewares will be sorted by this number and executed in order. So

```
{
"A": 200,
"B" : 400,
"C" : 300
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
"C" : 200
"A": 100,
"B" : 400,
}
```

Both would execute middleware in order `A, C, B`